# I want extract string

Tags: java

I have one string like

```
s1 = "Plug 1:L2SAEJ1772 Plug 2:L2SAEJ1772 Plug 3:L2SAEJ1772";
```

I want to print it like

```
Plug 1:L2SAEJ1771

Plug 2:L2SAEJ1772

Plug 3:L2SAEJ1773
```

Is it possible? If yes, then help me.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String s1 = "Plug 1:L2SAEJ1772 Plug 2:L2SAEJ1772 Plug 3:L2SAEJ1772";
s1 = s1.replaceAll( " P", "\nP" );
System.out.println( s1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression with lookahead (this way you don't "lose" the word 'Plug'):

```
String[] splitted = s1.split(" (?=Plug)");
for (String s : splitted) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cut split the String when theres a " P" (a whitespace and a P)
check s1.split() which needs regex
or you could go through the string in a for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) and check if the condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

your example need to be changed. As the input String does not end with `71`, `72`, `73`

```
    String s1="Plug 1:L2SAEJ1771 Plug 2:L2SAEJ1772 Plug 3:L2SAEJ1773";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Plug\\s\\d:\\w*\\b");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s1);
    while(m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group());
```

returns

```
Plug 1:L2SAEJ1771
Plug 2:L2SAEJ1772
Plug 3:L2SAEJ1773
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple regexp do the trick `:\w+`

You need only drop `:` from each extracted line.